# How to merge different columns into a new one made with the merged columns' name

Tags: r

I'm trying to clean my dataset. The dataset comes from a survey that had a randomizer. It displayed different scenarios to each participant.
My dataset now has a column for each different scenario with the name I chose for it (e.g.: A_SM_GIL or D_DF_GIL etc.). The underscore "*" separates the different scenarios variables that are combined together to form a new scenario. A*, D_, B_, N_ are the timing for a disclosure message during the advertising, respectively AFTER, DURING, BEFORE,and NONEF. SM_, and DF_, stand for the type of terminology used. Respectively SYNTHETIC MEDIA, and DEEPFAKE. The last bit, LOR_, GIL_, describes the brand's ad. Respectively L'Oreal, Gillette.

What I am left now is a bunch of columns that show with a "1" the scenario each observation was exposed to before answering a 7point likert scale to measure their attitudes towards the ad shown. The scale used is called ADTEST (AD_) and has different items (BORING_1, IRRITATING_1, etc).

Only 1 scenario for observation is possible. So one observation will have a column with 1 and all the others with NAs.

[image: Example]

My goal is to compare the different scenarios' attitudes. For example, studying if positioning the disclosure before the ad makes a difference than positioning it after the ad. I would like to plot the different answers (using a 7 point likert scale i.e.: AD_BORING_1 etc) people gave but divided into the different scenarios to compare them.

```
structure(list(D_DF_GIL = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 
1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 
1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 
1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), A_SM_GIL = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 
NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA), A_DF_GIL = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 
NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), N_DF_GILL = c(1, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 
NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA), AD_BORING_1 = c("7", 
"6", "5", "3", "4", "3", "5", "2", "4", "5", "3", "2", "5", "3", 
"4", "4", "5", "5", "1", "1", "4", "7", "4", "4", "3", "6", "1", 
"5", "2", "5", "3", "2", "2", "7", "6", "6", "6", "5", "4", "4", 
"6", "7", "3", "2", "1", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "6", "4", "5", 
"3", "5", "2", "7", "5", "2", "2", "3", "1", "5", "5", "4", "5", 
"1", "3", "2", "6", "5", "1", "3", "3", "5", "6", "5", "6", "2", 
"3", "5", "6", "5", "4", "6", "5", "4", "3", "5", "5", "4", "6", 
"2", "4", "6", "3", "4", "5", "3", "2", "6", "6", "5", "6", "3", 
"2", "6", "5", "4", "2", "3", "6", "4", "7", "3", "1", "4", "4", 
"5", "4", "2", "5", "6", "3", "5", "6", "4", "2", "5", "5", "3", 
"2", "3", "1", "6", "2", "1", "5", "5", "2", "6", "1", "6", "5", 
"2", "5", "2", "2", "4", "2", "2", "4", "4", "6", "3", "5", "5", 
"3", "2", "4", "7", "4", "4", "2", "5", "3", "2", "3", "3", "4", 
"2", "5", "6", "4", "4", "7", "4", "6", "3", "4", "2", "4", "3", 
"2", "6", "5", "5", "5", "4", "2", "3", "3", "5", "5", "6", "6", 
"7", "4", "2", "6", "3", "6", "4", "2", "7", "6", "4", "3", "2", 
"5", "5", "6", "5", "2", "7", "2", "3", "5", "2", "3", "5", "5", 
"5", "2", "4", "3", "5", "2", "3", "3", "2", "5", "5", "3", "3", 
"5", "3", "2", "5", "3", "7", "5", "5", "5", "4", "2", "4", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "2", "5", "7", "6", "4", "5", "6", "3", "5", "3", 
"2", "4", "5", "5", "3", "1", "4", "7", "5", "6", "3", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "5", "4", "1", "5", "2", "3", "7", "3", "4", "5", "3", 
"3", "5", "5", "2", "5", "4", "5", "2", "6", "2", "6", "4", "2", 
"3", "4", "6", "3", "2", "5", "2", "6", "2", "1", "3", "4", "1", 
"2", "5", "4", "3", "7", "5", "6", "6", "3", "4", "2", "4", "5", 
"2", "4", "3", "3", "2", "2", "3", "5", "3", "1", "3", "2", "2", 
"4", "2", "2", "3", "1", "4", "2", "5", "2", "5", "5", "5", "2", 
"5", "5", "4", "2", "7", "5", "5", "3", "4", "5", "3", "4", "3", 
"2", "5"), AD_IRRITATING_1 = c("4", "7", "3", "5", "4", "3", 
"4", "4", "4", "3", "4", "2", "2", "4", "1", "2", "1", "4", "1", 
"1", "4", "7", "5", "4", "2", "2", "6", "4", "2", "5", "1", "2", 
"2", "4", "2", "5", "4", "6", "4", "4", "7", "6", "3", "2", "1", 
"4", "2", "2", "4", "2", "7", "5", "2", "5", "2", "2", "6", "2", 
"5", "2", "2", "4", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "5", "1", "4", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "4", "5", "3", "5", "5", "1", "4", "4", "5", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "2", "2", "4", "2", "5", "7", "4", "5", 
"3", "2", "1", "4", "6", "3", "6", "3", "2", "6", "2", "3", "2", 
"2", "4", "2", "7", "3", "1", "4", "5", "2", "4", "1", "5", "5", 
"5", "5", "6", "2", "3", "5", "5", "2", "2", "3", "2", "6", "2", 
"1", "4", "2", "2", "5", "2", "2", "3", "2", "4", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "4", "5", "5", "1", "5", "2", "5", "1", "2", "2", "4", 
"5", "2", "4", "3", "2", "5", "2", "4", "2", "2", "4", "3", "5", 
"5", "3", "3", "1", "5", "2", "5", "6", "3", "4", "2", "6", "4", 
"4", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "4", "1", "6", "3", "2", "5", "1", 
"4", "5", "2", "2", "2", "6", "1", "1", "2", "3", "5", "7", "5", 
"7", "2", "3", "2", "3", "2", "1", "2", "5", "2", "4", "4", "6", 
"2", "3", "3", "1", "5", "4", "4", "3", "4", "4", "2", "4", "4", 
"5", "4", "6", "4", "4", "2", "5", "2", "2", "2", "7", "2", "3", 
"6", "5", "3", "3", "6", "1", "6", "2", "2", "5", "4", "2", "4", 
"1", "2", "4", "6", "4", "1", "2", "4", "2", "2", "4", "3", "1", 
"2", "2", "4", "4", "3", "5", "2", "4", "4", "5", "5", "3", "5", 
"4", "2", "2", "4", "5", "4", "2", "5", "2", "4", "3", "2", "1", 
"2", "2", "6", "5", "2", "1", "2", "1", "3", "6", "4", "4", "6", 
"3", "4", "4", "2", "2", "1", "4", "1", "2", "3", "2", "2", "5", 
"2", "3", "7", "7", "3", "2", "2", "3", "3", "1", "5", "2", "1", 
"4", "2", "5", "2", "5", "4", "4", "2", "5", "6", "2", "1", "2", 
"4", "4", "2", "5", "2", "4", "2", "5", "2", "7")), row.names = c(NA, 
-367L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I was thinking I could create a new column made of the other columns' name if a condition is met (in this case the fact that a column has a 1 and not NA).

Something like this

[image: Example result]

Another problem is all around the dataset there are other columns, so I need to specify exactly the columns to analyze.

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Please share sample data as copy/pasteable code, not pictures of tables. `dput()` is a friendly way to make copy/pasteable sample data, e.g, `dput(your_data[1:10, c("D_DF_LOR", "D_SM_LOR", ...)])` to share the first 10 rows of the mentioned columns, including all class and structure information.

Comment: I just added it to the question. Sorry for not having it done before. Still new

Comment: Your data has other columns in it. How do you want those columns to be treated?

Comment: The other columns are the answers to the scenario shown. For example if observation n.1 was randomly assigned to scenario A_SM_GIL he then had to reply to question AD_BORING_1 with a 7 point likert scale. The same question was asked to everyone, the only difference is the scenario they were assigned to. My goal is to compare the different answers to AD_BORING_1 and see how they differ for each different scenario

Comment: @Onyambu I think the short answer is that the other columns should be unchanged.

Comment: correct @GregorThomas

Comment: @Andrea how do you want to identify the scenario columns? Is there a pattern to their names? Or the first X columns are scenarios? Or you want to specify their names manually? Something else?

Comment: @GregorThomas the columns are one next to each other so a solution like [xx:xx] where xx are the number of the columns could work.

Comment: If something similar to the answer given like ```cols = dummy1:dummy3``` is possible is even better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation of Answer

Here you can get what I think you're after with two successive applications of `tidyr::pivot_longer()`.

1. The first `pivot_longer()` consolidates all the different scenarios into a single column so there is still one row per participant and one column that indicates what scenario group that participant was in.
2. Next you use `pivot_longer()` again to get the different adjectives into a single column.
3. I run a `dplyr::mutate()` with `stringr::str_extract()` to parse the `adjective` column.
4. Since you have some important metadata embedded in the scenario name, you can parse that out with `tidyr::separate()`
5. Also it looks like you have two different spellings of `GIL`/`GILL` so I cleaned that up which will help them sort together, but omit if that was intentional.
6. Since these seem like discrete variables I think it will be easier downstream if you convert them all to `factors` with `mutate(across(everything(), factor))`.

Once cleaned in this way, the data should be much easier to work with and visualize.

### Main Answer

```r
library(tidyverse)

d <- structure(list(D_DF_GIL = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), A_SM_GIL = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA), A_DF_GIL = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), N_DF_GILL = c(1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA), AD_BORING_1 = c("7", "6", "5", "3", "4", "3", "5", "2", "4", "5", "3", "2", "5", "3", "4", "4", "5", "5", "1", "1", "4", "7", "4", "4", "3", "6", "1", "5", "2", "5", "3", "2", "2", "7", "6", "6", "6", "5", "4", "4", "6", "7", "3", "2", "1", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "6", "4", "5", "3", "5", "2", "7", "5", "2", "2", "3", "1", "5", "5", "4", "5", "1", "3", "2", "6", "5", "1", "3", "3", "5", "6", "5", "6", "2", "3", "5", "6", "5", "4", "6", "5", "4", "3", "5", "5", "4", "6", "2", "4", "6", "3", "4", "5", "3", "2", "6", "6", "5", "6", "3", "2", "6", "5", "4", "2", "3", "6", "4", "7", "3", "1", "4", "4", "5", "4", "2", "5", "6", "3", "5", "6", "4", "2", "5", "5", "3", "2", "3", "1", "6", "2", "1", "5", "5", "2", "6", "1", "6", "5", "2", "5", "2", "2", "4", "2", "2", "4", "4", "6", "3", "5", "5", "3", "2", "4", "7", "4", "4", "2", "5", "3", "2", "3", "3", "4", "2", "5", "6", "4", "4", "7", "4", "6", "3", "4", "2", "4", "3", "2", "6", "5", "5", "5", "4", "2", "3", "3", "5", "5", "6", "6", "7", "4", "2", "6", "3", "6", "4", "2", "7", "6", "4", "3", "2", "5", "5", "6", "5", "2", "7", "2", "3", "5", "2", "3", "5", "5", "5", "2", "4", "3", "5", "2", "3", "3", "2", "5", "5", "3", "3", "5", "3", "2", "5", "3", "7", "5", "5", "5", "4", "2", "4", "2", "3", "4", "5", "2", "5", "7", "6", "4", "5", "6", "3", "5", "3", "2", "4", "5", "5", "3", "1", "4", "7", "5", "6", "3", "3", "4", "5", "6", "5", "4", "1", "5", "2", "3", "7", "3", "4", "5", "3", "3", "5", "5", "2", "5", "4", "5", "2", "6", "2", "6", "4", "2", "3", "4", "6", "3", "2", "5", "2", "6", "2", "1", "3", "4", "1", "2", "5", "4", "3", "7", "5", "6", "6", "3", "4", "2", "4", "5", "2", "4", "3", "3", "2", "2", "3", "5", "3", "1", "3", "2", "2", "4", "2", "2", "3", "1", "4", "2", "5", "2", "5", "5", "5", "2", "5", "5", "4", "2", "7", "5", "5", "3", "4", "5", "3", "4", "3", "2", "5"), AD_IRRITATING_1 = c("4", "7", "3", "5", "4", "3", "4", "4", "4", "3", "4", "2", "2", "4", "1", "2", "1", "4", "1", "1", "4", "7", "5", "4", "2", "2", "6", "4", "2", "5", "1", "2", "2", "4", "2", "5", "4", "6", "4", "4", "7", "6", "3", "2", "1", "4", "2", "2", "4", "2", "7", "5", "2", "5", "2", "2", "6", "2", "5", "2", "2", "4", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "5", "1", "4", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "4", "5", "3", "5", "5", "1", "4", "4", "5", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "2", "2", "4", "2", "5", "7", "4", "5", "3", "2", "1", "4", "6", "3", "6", "3", "2", "6", "2", "3", "2", "2", "4", "2", "7", "3", "1", "4", "5", "2", "4", "1", "5", "5", "5", "5", "6", "2", "3", "5", "5", "2", "2", "3", "2", "6", "2", "1", "4", "2", "2", "5", "2", "2", "3", "2", "4", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "4", "5", "5", "1", "5", "2", "5", "1", "2", "2", "4", "5", "2", "4", "3", "2", "5", "2", "4", "2", "2", "4", "3", "5", "5", "3", "3", "1", "5", "2", "5", "6", "3", "4", "2", "6", "4", "4", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "4", "1", "6", "3", "2", "5", "1", "4", "5", "2", "2", "2", "6", "1", "1", "2", "3", "5", "7", "5", "7", "2", "3", "2", "3", "2", "1", "2", "5", "2", "4", "4", "6", "2", "3", "3", "1", "5", "4", "4", "3", "4", "4", "2", "4", "4", "5", 
"4", "6", "4", "4", "2", "5", "2", "2", "2", "7", "2", "3", "6", "5", "3", "3", "6", "1", "6", "2", "2", "5", "4", "2", "4", "1", "2", "4", "6", "4", "1", "2", "4", "2", "2", "4", "3", "1", "2", "2", "4", "4", "3", "5", "2", "4", "4", "5", "5", "3", "5", "4", "2", "2", "4", "5", "4", "2", "5", "2", "4", "3", "2", "1", "2", "2", "6", "5", "2", "1", "2", "1", "3", "6", "4", "4", "6", "3", "4", "4", "2", "2", "1", "4", "1", "2", "3", "2", "2", "5", "2", "3", "7", "7", "3", "2", "2", "3", "3", "1", "5", "2", "1", "4", "2", "5", "2", "5", "4", "4", "2", "5", "6", "2", "1", "2", "4", "4", "2", "5", "2", "4", "2", "5", "2", "7")), row.names = c(NA, -367L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# make labels in case that helps
likert_breaks <- c("Strongly Disagree", "Somewhat Disagree", "Slightly Disagree", "Neutral", "Slightly Agree", "Somewhat Agree", "Strongly Agree")

# transform to long format and parse out metadata
d_long <- d %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = !starts_with("AD"), 
               names_to = "group", 
               values_to = "drop", 
               values_drop_na = T) %>%
  select(-drop) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("AD"),
               names_to = "adjective",
               values_to = "likert") %>% 
  mutate(adjective = str_extract(adjective, "(?<=_)(.*)(?=_)")) %>% 
  separate(group, into = c("pretreat", "treat", "ad")) %>% 
  mutate(ad = if_else(ad == "GILL", "GIL", ad)) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), factor))
  
str(d_long)
#> tibble [150 x 5] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>  $ pretreat : Factor w/ 3 levels "A","D","N": 3 3 1 1 2 2 3 3 2 2 ...
#>  $ treat    : Factor w/ 2 levels "DF","SM": 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#>  $ ad       : Factor w/ 1 level "GIL": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#>  $ adjective: Factor w/ 2 levels "BORING","IRRITATING": 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...
#>  $ likert   : Factor w/ 7 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 7 4 4 4 2 4 4 4 3 4 ...
```

---

### Bonus: Plotting

Since I got the impression you were hoping to look at the response profile by treatment group I wanted to provide some code to get you a plot of that fashion. Here there are a couple of important steps to make sure you get all of the bars in all plots in the right position.

1. Above we turned all the variables into `factor`s to ensure they can keep even empty levels.
2. Then we use `dplyr::summarize(n = n())` to count the responses per group per likert score.
3. Because the variables are all `factor`s we can then use `tidyr::complete()` to expand out all of the groups and fill `0` when there was no response of that type. This way we will force the graph to keep space for every bar even if it wasn't observed in the data.

```r
# bonus: plot the data
d_long %>% 
  group_by(across(everything())) %>% 
  summarize(n = n(), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  complete(pretreat, treat, ad, adjective, likert, fill = list(n = 0)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = adjective, y = n, fill = likert)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  facet_grid(pretreat ~ treat) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(option = "A", begin = 0, end = 0.85, labels = likert_breaks, drop = F) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Glad it helped. It would be great if you can update your question to more clearly articulate exactly what you're trying to do (based on your new understanding) so that if someone finds it in the future they can understand what's being asked and how it connects to the solutions offered. I had the benefit of working off additional information not present in the question.

Comment: I hope this clarifies a bit more

Comment: Yep, that's great. I think it's more clear for future reference now!

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is transform many dummy variables to one factor variable (with levels corresponding to dummy variable names).

I give a small reproducible example similar to your data:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(dummy1 = c(NA, 1, NA, NA), 
                      dummy2 = c(1, NA, 1, NA), dummy3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 1)), 
                 .Names = c("dummy1", "dummy2", "dummy3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df
#>   dummy1 dummy2 dummy3
#> 1     NA      1     NA
#> 2      1     NA     NA
#> 3     NA      1     NA
#> 4     NA     NA      1

df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = dummy1:dummy3, names_to = "dummy", values_to = "value", values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(dummy = as.factor(dummy)) %>%
  dplyr::select(-value)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 1
#>   dummy 
#>   <fct> 
#> 1 dummy2
#> 2 dummy1
#> 3 dummy2
#> 4 dummy3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

UPDATE: After posting your data, I simplified to only the `pivot_longer` (the `mutate` transformed `dummy` to factor, the `select` just dropped the `value` column that you don't need).

```
df %>%
    tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = D_DF_GIL:N_DF_GILL, names_to = "dummy", values_to = "value", values_drop_na = TRUE)
# A tibble: 75 x 4
   AD_BORING_1 AD_IRRITATING_1 dummy     value
   <chr>       <chr>           <chr>     <dbl>
 1 7           4               N_DF_GILL     1
 2 4           4               A_SM_GIL      1
 3 2           4               D_DF_GIL      1
 4 4           4               N_DF_GILL     1
 5 3           4               D_DF_GIL      1
 6 3           1               N_DF_GILL     1
 7 2           2               A_DF_GIL      1
 8 6           5               A_SM_GIL      1
 9 4           4               A_SM_GIL      1
10 1           1               N_DF_GILL     1
# ... with 65 more rows
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work :/

Comment: I added the dput() for a better understanding. My bad for not having it done before. The dummies are the one I want to merge together, the others are the values form the survey for each scenario randomly shown (dummies)

Comment: The solution I provided works, but now, after you posted your data, I see that most of your observations are `NA` for all dummy variables. It seems that most of your participants did not participate in any scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
scenario_cols = df %>%
  select(D_DF_GIL:N_DF_GILL) %>%
  names
  
df$new_col = scenario_cols[apply(
  df[scenario_cols], 1, 
  \(x) if(all(is.na(x))) NA else which.max(x)
)]
df$new_col
 #  [1] "N_DF_GILL" NA          NA          NA          "A_SM_GIL"  NA          NA          "D_DF_GIL" 
 #  [9] "N_DF_GILL" NA          NA          NA          NA          "D_DF_GIL"  NA          NA         
 # [17] NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA         
 # [25] NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          "N_DF_GILL" NA         
 # [33] "A_DF_GIL"  NA          NA          "A_SM_GIL"  NA          NA          NA          "A_SM_GIL" 
 # ...
```